# Dyanamically create a table and display data using JQuery

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

In my ASP.NET 4.0 application I recieve an object called GeneralQuestions from my WCF service. I need to populate the data from the object in the below shown format.

**GenearlQuestions object has the following properties**

```
OrderId
Header
QuestionContent

QuestionType (Based on this value I have to create a Dropdown or Radiobutton or Text box)

SubQuestions ( This is a property of type class which has OrderId, Header, QuestionContent, QuestionType properties. For example Question 15)
```

Can somebody guide me how can I accomplish this using JQuery.

Answer (score 1):

I would look into [jQuery Template](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.template/).

It 'pastes' JSON into a template, like for example, your table :).

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative which I really like is [ejs templates](http://embeddedjs.com/).  It has a syntax a lot more like server tags and it's a bit easier for me to use :)

Answer (score 1):

using only jQuery, assuming you have a `<div id='formContainer'>` in your html:

```
formContainer = $('#formContainer');

row = $('<div>', {'class':'formRow'}).appendTo(formContainer);
    $('<label>', {text:'Name', for:'inputName'}).appendTo(row);
    $('<input>', {type:'text', id:'inputName'}).appendTo(row);

row = $('<div>', {'class':'formRow'}).appendTo(formContainer);
    $('<label>', {text:'Password', for:'inputPassword'}).appendTo(row);
    $('<input>', {type:'password', id:'inputPassword'}).appendTo(row);

... and so on ...
```

Of course, this is not an exact answer to your question, but you get the idea.